# Whenever I open new project in android studio...its takes too much time

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jetbrains-ide, lag

Like I'm creating a new project like appdemo in empty activity but it taking too much time to open that project...it keeps downloading plugging,gradle for almost every new project which I create...also updating indexes takes too much time... what's the fault here? how can I stop it...

I tried installing and uninstalling new versions of android studio but this problem remains constant every time...I want to know if I can stop it and save my time...